# Traversing two BSTs inorder in an orderly fashion

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

These days I've been trying to implement a function that my professor has asked us to do, as a challenge, but I'm unable to think of any way possible of doing it, so I'm here to see if anyone can shed some light into this.

This will just be about the algorithm to do it, but I'm actually programming this in C++, using a BSTree programmed according to the basic specification (insert,delete,member operations).

The problem is the following:

Assuming that each node of a tree contains a number in absolute number, and we have two different BST: one to store negative numbers, and the other one to store positive numbers. We may call them negBST and posBST. For example, if we input the numbers `-2 2 5 8 -4 -5 -3 -6`, these would be our two trees:

```
2                        2
 \                        \
  4                        5
 / \                        \
3   5                        8
     \
      6
Negative BST               Positive BST
```

The objective is to print them both ordered, so, in this case, it would print:

```
2 -2 -3 -4 5 -5 -6 8
```

And now, here comes the challenge: Is it actually possible to do this without using any other auxiliary dynamic data structures (like queues, stacks, lists, etc)...?

EDIT: 
      The example provided might be a bit confusing, since the depth of the trees might vary.

Comment: Well if your trees have a fixed maximum depth, you can use fixed-size arrays to store the current "path" for both trees as you recurse through them simultaneously (where at each value you compare which of the 2 you're looking at is lower, record it, and increment that tree's position).

Comment: @Dave That would indeed work, but sadly just in the case if both trees have a fixed maximum depth, as you've stated :(

Comment: @SergioSánchez Consider also consider looking at and seeing if my answer can help you, or give some feedback on it (and I might learn something)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple but inefficient solution would be to iterate a variable `n` from zero to `MAX_NUMBER` and check for each iteration and tree, if the number `n` is saved in the tree. If yes, print it (negative for the negative tree of course).

You can also do two depth first searches in parallel. On each iteration you compare in which tree the next search step would yield the lower number. Print the number from the respective tree and advance the respective search.

**In a bit more detail:** You initialize two DFSs. This gives you one path in each tree pointing to the first element respectively. Now you compare the elements, select the tree with the lower element. Print the element (with a minus if required) and advance the DFS in the tree you have selected. This gives you the next element in this tree. Again, you compare the next elements in both trees, select the smaller one, et cetera.

Here some Javascript/C-like pseudocode:

```
// let's assume a DFS and its status is represented by an object
// dfs.next() returns the next number and advances the search
// dfs.peekNext() only returns the next number

var dfsPos = initDFS(posBST);
var dfsNeg = initDFS(negBST);

while (!dfsPos.hasFinished() || !dfsNeg.hasFinished()) {
    if (dfsPos.hasFinished())
        print('-' +dfsNeg.next());
    else if (dfsNeg.hasFinisehd())
        print(dfsPos.next());
    else if (dfsPos.peekNext() < dfsNeg.peekNext()) 
        print(dfsPos.next());
    else
        print('-' +dfsNeg.next());
}
```

Comment: That might indeed work, in an inefficient way, but should work. I'll keep this question alive while I manage to translate it to C++, or if someone shares a maybe more efficient way to do this, thank you!

Comment: I just updated the answer. The second approach should not be inefficient. It is actually the fastest way.

Comment: I'm actually not able to fully understand how would the second method exactly work. Could you expand a little bit the explanation, if possible? I've thought of your answer as using pre-order traversing (DFS) and doing the comparations, but i'm guessing I have understood incorrectly your answer since that doesn't really lead me anywhere, it actually gives some numbers in wrong order.

Comment: I added some more detail + pseudocode to the answer.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, it's much clearer now, the problem now is how to translate the DFS to a non-object approach, but that goes beyond the scope of the question. I'm marking this as answer, thanks again!

Comment: It is same question as merging two sorted array isn't ?

Comment: @newbie_old Well, it's definitely related. In my answer I just consider the trees as sequences from which you can draw elements in order, so you could do the same with arrays.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume negBST and posBST each, on their own, contain unique keys.

Instead of trying to treat two separate BST:s in parallel/simultaneously, you could create a single BST, say *commonBST*, which allow non-unique entries. Generally, this is tricky and can mess up fundamental BST properties, but in this special case, it will work, as:

- For our array of numbers (example: `-2 2 5 8 -4 -5 -3 -6`), for constructing the *single* BST commonBST, look only at absolute value of each number; say `KEY = abs(number)`, and associate the sign of number to an additional property for `KEY`, say `KEY.sign`. Each possible `KEY` can only exist in the following states:

  - nil (not present in tree)
  - (`KEY`, `KEY.keySign=-1` for -)
  - (`KEY`, `KEY.keySign=+1` for +)
  - (`KEY`, both signs, `KEY.keySign=0`)
- If we already have two trees (and not the initial array that created the two trees), we simply add negBST to posBST to achieve the commonBST described above.

Since negBST and posBST only contain unique keys, the only degeneracy in the keys for commonBST is the possible existence of both a + and - occurrence for a specific KEY.

Using this schema, we can create the commonBST as (using your number array as example):

```
For key C:
    C*: C contains both +C and -C (keySign = 0)
    C : C contains only one of +C and -C (get sign from keySign)

Example binary tree for numbers [-2, 2, 5, 8, -4, -5, -3, -6]:

    2*
     \
     5*
   /    \
  4      8
 /      /
3      6
```

The following swift code constructs such a tree

```
// adapted from "regular" BST in Swift from: 
// http://waynewbishop.com/swift/binary-search-trees/

//generic binary search tree
public class AVLTree {
    var key: Int?
    var keySign: Int? // -1 or 1 for unique entries, 0 if both
    var left: AVLTree?
    var right: AVLTree?

    init() { }

    //add item based on its value
    func addNode(key: Int) {

        //check for the head node
        if (self.key == nil) {
            self.key = abs(key)
            self.keySign = abs(key)/key
            return
        }

        // check for duplicate key
        if (abs(key) == self.key) {
            self.keySign = 0
        }

        //check the left side of the tree
        else if (abs(key) < self.key) {
            if (self.left != nil) {
                left!.addNode(key)
            }
            else {
                //create a new left node
                let leftChild : AVLTree = AVLTree()
                leftChild.key = abs(key)
                leftChild.keySign = abs(key)/key
                self.left = leftChild
            }
        }

        //check the right side of the tree
        else if (abs(key) > self.key) {
            if (self.right != nil) {
                right!.addNode(key)
            }
            else {
                //create a new right node
                let rightChild : AVLTree = AVLTree()
                rightChild.key = abs(key)
                rightChild.keySign = abs(key)/key
                self.right = rightChild
            }
        }
    }
}

let numberList : Array<Int> = [-2, 2, 5, 8, -4, -5, -3, -6]

//create a new BST instance
var root = AVLTree()

//sort each item in the list
for number in numberList {
    root.addNode(number)
}
```

This uses a pure imperative approach, so you should be able to use it as detailed pseudocode for your language of choice.

The commonBST can be expanded just a a regular BST, but simply check the property `keySign` when expanding each key.

- If `keySign=1`, `print(key)`.
- If `keySign=-1`, `print(-key)`.
- If `keySign=0`, `print(-key)` & `print(key)` (or your order of choice).

This should have the complexity as any regular BST, O(log n) on average for insertion and lookup.

Comment: This is a good way to do it, plain and simple. The problem resides in the restrictions my professor has given me, which unfortunately doesn't allow me to create any auxiliary data structure to perform the operation, but I'm upvoting this since it might help anyone else. Thanks!

Comment: @SergioSánchez Ah I kind of missed that, my bad!